# Integration issues with Geminipro in Android application which is using giraffe and Gradle 6.4

Tags: android, large-language-model, gemini

I'm currently working on an Android application using Giraffe and Gradle version 6.4. I'm trying to integrate Geminipro into my project after upgrade to iguana, but I'm encountering several errors during the process.

Here's a summary of my setup:

Giraffe framework
Gradle version 6.4
I've followed the documentation for Geminipro, but the integration is not going smoothly, and I'm facing multiple errors. Could someone with experience in Geminipro integration provide guidance or steps to successfully integrate it into an Android application with the mentioned stack?

Any insights, sample configurations, or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried to update to iguana and use its dependency and update compilesdkversion to 34 but it's not working

Comment: Pls post your code, your error logs here so we can help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not able to build the code I am getting something "null extracted" error, I have removed jetifier in my code then it is working fine but I can't remove jetifier,